Where is the fault in this proof regarding matrix equivalence
An exercise I am doing asks 'If two matrices are square matrices and have matrix equivalent squares, must they be matrix equivalent?'
There's an easy counterexample to prove that they aren't necessarily matrix equivalent as
$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ have matrix-equivalent squares but themselves aren't matrix-equivalent. However I tried to approach the question generally and came up with a proof that such matrices are necessarily matrix-equivalent - where is the fault in this proof?
Proof
Let $A, B$ be square matrices, then we are given that $A^2 = PB^2Q = PBBQ$ for nonsingular $P, Q$
Therefore, $A = \sqrt{PBBQ} = \sqrt{P}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{Q} = \sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q}$
If $\sqrt{P}$ and $\sqrt{Q}$ are nonsingular, then $A$ is matrix equivalent to $B$
Let $U = \sqrt{P}, V = \sqrt{Q}$, then $UU = P$ and $VV = Q$
The product of nonsingular matrices produces a nonsingular matrix, and any product involving a singular matrix produces a singular matrix, therefore $U, V$ must be nonsingular
Then it follows that $A$ is matrix-equivalent to $B$
I assume the error is in the square root step as every other step looks sound to me, but I can't catch what's wrong.

Square as in $n \times n$ size, not square as in 'is the square of another matrix', sorry for the confusion. The question phrased it like that but have edited it for clarity.

Why not? If we define $U = \sqrt{P}$, then $UU = P$ — or is there an issue with defining $U$ like that?

Yeah correct, that's not the 'square' I am referring to. But anyways, the matrix $0, 1, 0, 0$ wouldn't equal $P$ but it would be $B$ in the counterexample, as $0, 0, 0, 0$ and $0, 1, 0, 0$ have matrix-equivalent squares, so they are the $A^2$ and $B^2$ above, not the $P$ and $Q$.

Alright, I try to follow your proof with $A=0$ and $B$ the other matrix. Here is the mistake. So $0=\sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q}$ is impossible for invertible matrices $\sqrt{P},\sqrt{Q}$, because it would immediately give $B=0$, a contradiction.

What are you using the $\sqrt{}$ symbol to mean?

@DietrichBurde ah yes I see the contradiction there; am I correct to say that this implies that the only possible counterexamples are those where $A = 0$? As if $A \neq 0$ then the contradiction wouldn't hold as $B$ isn't necessarily $0$?

@Malady square root — so $\sqrt{P}$ returns a matrix $U$ such that $UU = P$

@tikis.tacos so it is multivalued. You do not get to apply it to both sides of an equation and retain equality.

@Malady isn't the sign insignificant if we are just interested in determining whether $\sqrt{P}$ is nonsingular or not? As in, from $A^2 = PBBQ$, the multivalued nature of sqrt means that $A = \sqrt{PBBQ}$ or $-\sqrt{PBBQ}$ — but in either case we just need to find out if $\sqrt{P}$ is nonsingular — because if this is nonsingular then $-\sqrt{P}$ is necessarily nonsingular as well, thus covering both cases. Further still, multivalued nature of sqrt means that $\sqrt{P} = U, -U$, but provided that $UU = P$, can't we determine that $U$ is nonsingular, and thus $-U$ is nonsingular too?

For matrices, there are many more square roots than just the two up to sign.

@Malady yep, I'd misunderstood this earlier, user1551's response helped show this too. Thanks for the help !

Actually, since $(\sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q})^2=\sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q}\sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q}$ is clearly not identical to $PBBQ$, there is no reason to believe that $\sqrt{PBBQ}=\sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q}$.
Anyway, there are a number of errors or ambiguities in your argument:

Square roots of a matrix, in general, are not unique. E.g. every matrix of the form $\pmatrix{1&x\\ 0&-1}$ is a square root of the $2\times2$ identity matrix. While $A^2=PBBQ$, if you take a square root of $PBBQ$, it is not true that this square root is necessarily equal to $A$. So, you cannot infer from $A^2=PBBQ$ that $A=\sqrt{PBBQ}$ without clarifying how the square root is taken.
Not all matrices have square roots. E.g. the $1\times1$ matrix $[-1]$ does not have a square root over $\mathbb R$. In your proof attempt, $\sqrt{P}$ and $\sqrt{Q}$ may simply not exist.
Even when $P,Q$ and $PBBQ$ have square roots, they may not possess any square roots that satisfy the equality $\sqrt{PBBQ}=\sqrt{P}B\sqrt{Q}$. E.g. consider the real matrices $P=\pmatrix{4\\ &1},B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$ and $Q=\pmatrix{1\\ &4}$. Note that

$P$ has only four square roots $R_1=\pmatrix{2\\ &1},R_2=\pmatrix{-2\\ &1},-R_1$ and $-R_2$;
$B^2$ has only two square roots $B$ and $-B$;
$Q$ has only four square roots $S_1=\pmatrix{1\\ &2},S_2=\pmatrix{-1\\ &2},-S_1$ and $-S_2$;
$PBBQ=\pmatrix{8&32\\ 2&8}$ has only two square roots $T=\pmatrix{2&8\\ \frac12&2}$ and $-T$.



Yet, it is easy to see that $T\ne\pm R_iBS_j$ because $R_iBS_j$ is an integer matrix but $T$ is not.

Thanks for the detailed answer, was very helpful in clarifying the errors. The point you make in your opening sentence in retrospect seems like an obvious one, it appears my understanding of the square root of a matrix product is wrong. From your other points 1 to 3 I can see how introducing the square root leaves a lot of room for ambiguous cases — once again, thanks for the detailed response.
